# (103) Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

The following errors are being logged in our proxy Apache logs while processing the request with Tomcat Server:

```
(103)Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed  
proxy: pass request body failed
```

We've a Apache reverse proxy which serves the request for the client from our Tomcat Server. Sometimes, the request from the proxy returns 502 with the above error. There are no error logs in Tomcat Server Logs correlated with the above errors in Proxy. Also, the request didn't timeout since some of the requests response time is 1 sec and our default timeout is 120 sec.

We've added ProxyBadHeader Ignore to our httpd configuration [Ref: 502 Proxy Error / Uploading from Apache (mod_proxy) to Tomcat 7] and still didn't see any errors in our Tomcat logs.

Have anyone seen this issue earlier?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this issue after upgrading one of our machines from Tomcat 6 to 7. Someone forgot to change the default apache-tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml file from our standard one and so the wrong password was getting checked by the server. Interestingly this results in the 502 Error you saw above. This can be avoided with some decent logging to determine it is actually an auth problem.